# Does anyone know how can we show Reports via Analytics API in Visualforce with direct linsk to records like in standard report?

Tags: apex, visualforce, analytics-api, reports-api

I'm trying to show a report in a visualforce page, with some custom filtering. The hurdle that I'm facing is, the report data comes in as static text. I would like to have a link for Lookup fields that point to the respective record and a Link for the Name field of the object to click open the record.

How can I do that. Just so you know, I don't want to ruin the report by adding ID values in the report and creating formula field and adding them to report and show links in the exported data in VF page. I'm looking for if there is some standard built in way to view the report in VF page with Links and can be browsed in Reports Tab with links to records as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much more studying I found out about the answer to this. The ReportDataCell Class has a "Value" property that returns the ID value and "Label" property that return Label for the cell.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_reports_reportdatacell.htm#apex_class_reports_reportdatacell

Comment: please mark this as a solution

Comment: I'll, stackexchange requires me to wait till tomorrow to mark it as an answer.